# Critique: Is my logo conveying what I want to communicate?

Tags: logo, critique

I'm working as a junior web designer. I want to redesign my portfolio, including that I'm also designing my logo.

This is the first time I'm designing a logo. I learnt guidelines and I designed my new logo.

What I want to communicate through my logo is:

1. It should clearly convey my profession i.e. designer.
2. I'm very much passionate about my profession, so I want to reflect the same in my logo.

[image: my logo - iambharat.co.in]
[image: logo in b/w]
[image: logo in single color bg]

Is my logo conveying what I want to convey? Also, if there is anything to improve in my logo please suggest it to me.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was blogging.

Comment: The gray version in particular looks like the colors don't go too well. I'd likely use a dark on the left to light on the right scheme for the second and third versions if you stick with this design

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying. do you mean the color combination is not good in 2nd and 3rd one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I like your style. It's well executed and easy on the eyes. But, to be totally honest, a pencil is probably not the best association with web design. Or are you doing professional mockups on paper and showing these to your clients?  If not, I think the symbol is a bit weak.

Comment: I usually start with analysis of requirements after that ill do a wireframes and some rough sketches in order to represent what is in my mind. I use dot grid book for wire framing. after that ill do a mockup design in PS. when it is reviewed by client i'll go with development. So, this is the process I do when designing a site. In this whole process I use Pencil to draw my ideas on the paper! So I thought it represents my work well.

Comment: @bharat If your focus isn't drawing it likely isn't the best symbol for you to use

Comment: hm.. ok then i'll design other version with some other concept!

Comment: maybe you could use the concept 'from pencil to pixel'. I like that, could be a nice logo.

Answer (score 0):

I think of you as some cartoonist, or some other person who likes to use a pencil a lot. 
Web designing is the last things that comes to my mind. I liked your design btw.

Comment: No i'm not a cartoonist. There is a reason for choosing pencil as my logo. As i already said, the first step i do in designing process after analysing requirements is drawing a rough sketches on paper. That is the moment when i implement ideas in my brain, the basic thing. to show the design we use tools like PS, wireframe tools etc. There are alternatives to those tools. Max the design process goes inside the mind.

Comment: So i thought pencil as a tool represents the work i do. I tried different alternatives of logo, but i couldn't find the best match. I know that my logo is a bit weak, i'm working on that. One more thing i'm thinking is, people could learn about my logo and from the second visit they can easily identify what my logo is.

Comment: I dont want to see how you work. I dont care if you use a pencil, pen or a hammer. I want my job finished!

Comment: Hi @killerprince182, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site! Also, your tone of voice in your last comment could be nicer, even though you made a correct point.

Comment: @PieBie In this case I am sorry. I was just trying to make a point!

Comment: @killerprince182 Sure, as I said, your point was valid. And I think the OP took the comment in the spirit it was intended. Still, this is the internet and it's easy to be mistaken for a troll while you're trying to make a valid point. A Smiley can help :)