# How can I assess whether I'm proper web designer?

Tags: website-design, designers

I was an Amature web designer before 3 years. Though I don't have proper knowledge in designing I want to become a web designer and I called myself as *designer*.

Though I didn't attended any design colleges I have a very strong passion towards. I read lot of design books and practised designing continuously. In these 3 years of time I learnt lot of things and I designed few websites.

I have a strong knowledge in HTML, CSS and Jquery.

I learnt basics of designing, different ways of selecting colors and what they communicate, typography basics, layouts, grids, how to make design choices and even more.

I feel very confident now, that I can proudly say "I'm a web designer".

Since I don't have any proper training and everything I learnt is self taught I just want to assess how good I am and am I eligible to be a *web designer*?

This is one of my recent designed page for sample.

[image: one of my recent work]

This is my [new logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54305/critique-is-my-logo-conveying-what-i-want-to-communicate) which I asked for critique review recently. I used proper design principles and Workflow in order to do all these things.

I know that there are lot of things to learn and experience matters to become an expert. As a beginner am I doing good? and am I eligible to be a *web designer*? Is there any way to assess my skills?

Comment: I can call myself a chef tomorrow... even if I still burn 80% of what I cook. You're free to call yourself a designer all you want. Whether or not you get and retain clients is a different matter.

Comment: I didn't mean how to call myself. What I mean is am I doing good as desginer and how can I assess my skills?

Comment: @bharat, I think this thread is also worth taking a look at: [How would I know how good of a designer I am?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13808/how-would-i-know-how-good-of-a-designer-i-am).

Comment: I think I'm looking for the same answer. But It didn't appeared when I searched. Anyway thanks for sharing the link @AndrewH :)

Comment: The many answers to [this old question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers) will provide you with a library of resources to develop your fundamental skills.

Comment: are people paying you to design web pages? if so, you are a web designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not a regulated profession. There are no required certificates, education, or licenses required. Anyone can call themselves a Web Designer without legal ramifications.

If you can create a website, even a simple one, then congratulations you're a web designer. Beyond that is a matter of are you good enough. Note I don't say good, I say good enough. Not everyone is working on multi-million dollar projects but if you're good enough to take on small clients needing a simple "brochure website" then you're still a *professional web designer*.

Well now I've introduced another word, *professional*. That you can use once you get paid to do web design.

Comment: Ryan points out the critical part of the *job*: getting paid. If clients pay you enough to make a living and they're happy at the end of the process, you're good to go. If you want to be good at the *craft* of design, that's going to take a lot of study and practical skill development. Clients care about that, they just don't realize it.